# scrollToRowAtIndexPath doesn't work for first cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to scroll to text field, inside table cell, when it begin editing.
It works fine for other table cells, except the first one:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview;
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

I have tested the value for [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell] it is set for first row and first section.

I think it has to do with the fact that heightForHeaderInSection for the first section is very big (covers about half the screen).

Comment: Because it's already at the top?

Comment: Do not assume the cell can be obtained from the text field using `textField.superview.superview`. The subview layout is different in different iOS versions and it could change.

Comment: OP already mentioned it is working for other cells, don't think this could be the problem in this question.

Comment: @Vizllx I didn't say it will solve the problem here. I'm simply pointing out that such code will fail under other versions of iOS even if it works now.

Comment: @rmaddy I seriously think that there is no need of pointing out such a issue which is irrelevant from the question asked. We should always stick with the problem what OP is facing,not futuristic issues ,it creates more conflicts.Suggestion should be provided once this issue is resolved.

Comment: IIRC that method does not bring FULL row visible, which you seem to expect. If any part of row is visible, then the method thinks it's done it's job. As fix, change tableView.contentOffset.y manually.

Comment: @Vizllx - Code that uses unpublished internal view hierarchies on Mac or iOS is notorious for breaking on major OS versions. This isn't a hypothetical problem, it happens all the time. Therefore, it's worth pointing out so that things can be done in a safer manner.

Comment: @JOM Thanks, but that's not the case, even if I make the cell not visible by increasing the header view to cover most of the screen, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue, just solved it from this blog [link](http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2012/10/15/scrolling-a-uitableview-when-displaying-the-keyboard/)

**Here is the process:**
*In  UITextFieldDelegate’s textFieldDidBeginEditing method only thing to be aware of here is that the delegate will be called before the keyboard is actually shown. To deal with that we delay the scrolling using delayed performance:*

```
-(void) scrollToCell:(NSIndexPath*) path {
    [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToCell:) withObject:path afterDelay:0.5f];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not help in my case

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a bug. I was able to work around this, by setting the table contentOffset:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = ...; // calculate offset for cell
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
    }];
}
```